# Can any one justify this two NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsdate

Why are these two fireDate different?

The date displayed in the log is wrong.

[image]

Comment: TimeZone, nothing to worry about it.

Comment: yes because when you log nsdate then it will display global(gmt+0) date. so after converting date into string using timezone then you will get proper date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date logged to console is correct, considering that there is no time zone offset (i.e., displayed for UTC). The date displayed in the quick look popover is adjusted for India Standard Time (which is offset +5:30 from UTC).

Answer (score 1):

You are from INDIA I guess and india Time zone is +5.30.
but in Log it showing +000 GMT right.

So if you add +5.30 in your Log Time Then You will get correct time which you can see during debugging.